# Data Migration Tool Removing Already Exist Values Of Magento2 Database

Tags: data-migration

I want know that data migration tool working with fresh database or with already exist values in Magento2.

Comment: Its better to do data migration on a fresh database.

Comment: There are many automated data migration tool in the market but I highly recommend you to use this service called litexxtension. It's quite a great product that I've used

Answer (score 1):

Always use a fresh database to migrate from Magento 1 to Magento 2.

If you migrate it with already existing database then highly probability to conflict database table id and it is always through an error.

You can not migrate 100% data in the existing database.

You can do the delta migration process with the same M2 database after the first migration process.

Comment: Can You tell me about delta migration process how i use?

Comment: After the first successful migration, If you need new data from Magento 1 then you need to do delta migration.

Comment: migration sucessful from magento1 to magento2. But i want to know how i do delta migration?

Comment: what is difference migration and delta migration?

Comment: Both are the same process. but delta migration is when you live your M2 instance then you get a new order, a product from M1 using delta migration.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the delta migration process with the same M2 database after the first migration process.

The first migration process is done with bin/magento **migrate:data** CLI command

The delta migration is done using bin/magento **migrate:delta** CLI command